# Applescript download & open link

Tags: email, applescript

I've set a rule in Apple Mail to run a "Download & Open link" applescript. I would like this script to download the url in the mail message and after downloading it should open the file.

No idea how to start on this. Here's the code that isn't working:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages newMessages
        repeat with newMessage in newMessages

            tell application "Mail"
                set contentLink to (content of newMessage)
            end tell

            set the destination_file to ("/Users/thomas/Downloads/file")

            tell application "URL Access Scripting"
                download contentLink to destination_file replacing yes
            end tell


        end repeat
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Comment: What does't work? What errors are you getting? Have you tested the different tell blocks by themselves? You should delete your own "answers" and edit your question and add code revisions there.

Comment: +1 on all points made. There isn't nearly enough information here to provide a solution.

Comment: **Please** stop adding answers to provide additional information. Just edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to download the link **into a string**, which is impossible unless you coerce the string into an `alias`. You could do this one of two ways.

1. Coerce the variable `destination_file` as it's initialized into an alias...

   ```
   set the destination_file to "/Users/thomas/Downloads/file/" as POSIX file as alias
   ```
2. Coerce the variable when you're downloading the link...

   ```
   download contentLink to destination_file as POSIX file as alias replacing yes
   ```

Once you've done that, all you need to do now is navigate to the folder where you downloaded the file and open it.

Example:

```
tell application "Finder" to open "Macintosh HD:Users:Anonymous:Downloads:example.txt" as alias
```